# Define maven profiles outside POM

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Is there a way to define my maven profiles outside POM file but **not** in **.m2/settings.xml**?
I want to define them in a **separate xml** file **inside** the **application** (way to work efficiently with maven 2 and 3) because I am using maven 2 and intend to switch to 3 soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until Maven 2.2.1 you could define your profiles into the profiles.xml file as a separate file but with Maven 3 this opportunity has been removed. The question ist why do you need a separate file for the profiles?

Comment: because i have lots of profiles, and each profile contains lots of properties, and pom file is getting so large.

Comment: What about using a super-pom that contains profiles, assuming they would apply across different project types? Your project poms can then use that parent pom without having to re-define all this common behavior.

Comment: url for such approach please in a separate answer would be preferable ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>prod</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>test</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And add a filter

```
<filters>
   <filter>src/test/resources/${build.profile.id}/config.properties</filter>
</filters>
```

And add any directory (dev, prod, test)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to go through [this maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) on build profiles, which describes the types of profiles and how each can be used.

As I see it, profiles cannot be defined outside `pom.xml` or `settings.xml`, if you want to use `maven 3`.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently migrating an application to maven3 from maven2. With maven 3 there is no possibility to have external profiles. But what can be done is to have external property files. This can be achieved by maven-properties-plugin

```
    <plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
 <executions>
  <!-- Associate the read-project-properties goal with the initialize phase,
   to read the properties file. -->
  <execution>
   <phase>initialize</phase>
   <goals>
    <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
    <files>
     <file>../com.tak/build.properties</file>
    </files>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

So here I have explained how to do that http://programtalk.com/java/migrate-from-maven2x-to-maven3x/